# Make adaptive-wrap tab aware

Tags: latex, auctex, wrapping, visual-line-mode

I am switching to AUCTeX as my LaTeX editor and need tab-aware automatic line wrapping. From [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559061/emacs-how-to-keep-the-indentation-level-of-a-very-long-wrapped-line) I gathered that `adaptive-wrap` is basically what I need.

How can I make `adaptive-wrap` aware of Tab-indentation?

On GitHub I already found [this](https://gist.github.com/tsavola/6222431) 'fork' of `adaptive-wrap` and [this](https://gist.github.com/evincarofautumn/0f4ad718747ee259d535) code to get Tab-awareness. Since I don't know any Elisp, I'm not sure these are safe to use with `GNU Emacs 24.5.1`.

Note that I cannot manually switch everything to space-indented code, as my current project is already very large.

Comment: you can automatically switch every file you edit to space-indented adding the following to your .emacs `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (untabify (point-min) (point-max))))`

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by _tab-aware automatic line wrapping_ and add some code showing the starting point and the desired result?

Comment: It simply means I want `adaptive-wrap` to work with tab indentation, which it does not. Just open any tab indented piece of TeX code and enable `visual-line-mode` and `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode` and you'll see.

Comment: I actually followed @matteol's comment for converting tabs to spaces to circumvent the issue, which seems to be a safe operation.

Comment: If it's about turning tabs into spaces, you can use the variable `TeX-auto-untabify` provided by AUCTeX and customize it to `t`.  AUCTeX then converts all tabs in your buffer into spaces when save your file(s).